# how i can use Linear Gradient color for navigation rail background in flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

how i can use Linear Gradient color for navigation rail background in flutter

my code

```
NavigationRail(
              elevation: 15,
              selectedIndex: _selectedIndex,
              onDestinationSelected: (int index) {
                if (_selectedIndex > index) {
                  newProductModel.changeIndex(index);
                } else {
                  err(context, 'باید به ترتیب مراحل را انجام دهید');
                }
              },
              labelType: NavigationRailLabelType.selected,
              backgroundColor: Colors.blue.withOpacity(0.5),
              destinations: [
                NavigationRailDestination(
                  icon: Icon(MdiIcons.variable),
                  selectedIcon: Icon(Icons.format_list_bulleted),
                  label: Text(
                    'اطلاعات کلی',
                    style: style,
                  ),
                ),
                NavigationRailDestination(
                  icon: Icon(Icons.bookmark_border),
                  selectedIcon: Icon(Icons.book),
                  label: Text(''),
                ),
                NavigationRailDestination(
                  icon: Icon(Icons.star_border),
                  selectedIcon: Icon(Icons.star),
                  label: Text(''),
                ),
```

i need to change  background color with Linear Gradient

Answer (score 0):

I think you can wrap your widget with container and give it a linear gradient.